# Batch file which runs a .class file inside a path

Tags: batch

I would like to make a batch file that:

1. Opens cmd.exe
2. Within that Command Prompt runs `cd C:\mywork\` then runs `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin` and at the final runs `java MCExploit` wich runs a .class file, but the final command shows some text like `omg|omg` so I need to be able to read that text.
3. Leaves the window open so that I can run additional commands if I wish to

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not open cmd.exe and run a batch file containing those commands?

Comment: I've tried several stuff, but none of them seems to work. I tried for example: `START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\mywork\" & "set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin" & "java MCExploit"` but it doesn't show the text I was talking about. When I do it manualy it works but when I do that from the batch I mentioned   above, it doesn't show the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a batch file with all your commands, for example:

   ```
   set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
   cd C:\mywork\
   java MCExploit
   ```
2. Create a shortcut to **Windows\System32\cmd.exe** and in the shortcut's Properties, ensure the **Target** field looks similar to the following:

   ```
   C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\MyCmds.bat
   ```
3. Done! Double-clicking the shortcut will open a Command Prompt window, execute your batch file and then return back to the prompt and await further orders from you.